# MVC - Passing a Type as an action parameter

Tags: model-view-controller, parameters, types, action

Can I pass a parameter of Type to the Action method in MVC via a HTML.ActionLink().

e.g.

```
public ActionResult Get(Type containerType, string name)
{
            throw new NotImplementedException("vkag");
}

<%=Html.ActionLink(flow.Source.Name, "Get", new { containerType = typeof(Worksheet), name = flow.Source.Name})%>
```

For some reason the type is always null. I also can't pass back a base type to allow for subtypes to be passed in it's place.

I don't know whether this is a limitation of the HTML ActionLink Helper or MVC.

I can't pass an Interface, I specify a  base type parameter and use sub type as an argument in the place of a base type parameter, and I can't seem to pass a Type back. I'm pretty stuck here.

Is there another HTML Helper that will help?

Can I do anything with model binding?

Can I modify the state of my model during an ActionLink invocation before control is passed to my action method?

Kind a stuck here. Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The types you can pass into Routes must be passable via a URL if you think about it.

You cannot pass a Type as it would have to be serialised. Why not pass the containerType as a string and convert it back to a Type in the action?

Comment: Thanks Thomas, thought about that would prefer to work with types is possible rather than a string.

Comment: Although, ultimately I'm trying to get NHibernate to resolve data of a given type from the database based on the Type passed to my action method. Makes sense why it doesn't work, but was hopnig that there was a work around.

Comment: Do you have many types? You could possibly use an Enum and that should serialize correctly (I think)

Comment: Hmm, sub ten sub types implementing an interface at the moment. So need to get info about the type being passed back from the view. My view model has a collection of subtypes confirming to a contract and would ideally like to accept the IContainer interface into the action method, but for obvious reasons can't. As much as I don't want to, might move to the type name in order to get things moving as I can't think of a way to do it otherwise.